# No Greeter on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gdm, unity-greeter

I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and now my greeter is gone.

After reboot my computer, I am automatically logged into my GUI.

I understand Ubuntu now uses GDM3, how can I enable/configure its greeter?

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl enable gdm.service && sudo systemctl start gdm.service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. **AutoLogin is On**

   Go to **Settings -> Details -> User -> Automatic Login**
2. **The Upgrade didn't complete properly**

   Go to the terminal and verify that the `ubuntu-desktop` package is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

   (`ubuntu-desktop` requires `gdm3` which requires `gnome-session` which manages the login session so, presuming you haven't changed any configs, ensuring ubuntu-desktop is installed should fix a lot of things.)

*There are more things that you could have messed up somehow, but these are the easiest to fix.*